# SVG clipPaths clipping objects more than expected. What could be the reason?

Tags: svg

I've recently found out that the clipPaths in SVG clip a bigger area than what's specified in the commands.

Below is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">

<defs>
<rect id="r1" x="100.85" y="100.39" width="200.51" height="100.72" fill="black"/>
<rect id="r2" x="100.85" y="100.39" width="200.51" height="100.72" fill="yellow"/>
<clipPath id="clip">
    <use xlink:href="#r2"/> 
</clipPath>
</defs>

<use xlink:href="#r1"/> 
<use xlink:href="#r2" clip-path="url(#clip)"/>  

</svg>
```

According to the code, the rect "r1" should be completely overlapped by the **clipped** rect "r2" and only r2 should be seen. But that's not the case. There is a black border seen on the output.

What could be the reason? As all browsers (Chrome, Firefox, Safari) seem to show the exact behavior, I was wondering if I made a mistake when understanding the specification.

I have also tried applying shape-rendering="crispEdges" attribute, wondering that Smoothing could be the culprit, but it made no difference in this case.

Further, I have found out that if the values are all integers (or maps to pixels exactly), this border goes away.

Would appreciate any input regarding this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The clip is working fine.  What you are seeing is the effects of anti-aliasing.

Because your rectangles are not perfectly aligned with the pixels of the screen, some border pixels of the rectangles are being drawn with less than 100% opacity.

So when the black rectangle is drawn, it has some border pixels that are draw as a mix of black and the background colour (white).

```
+-----+-----+- -
|grey |grey |
+-----+-----+  ..etc..
|black|black|
+-----+-----+- -
```

Then the yellow rectangle is being drawn exactly on top of it.  This time, the rectangle border pixels are being drawn as a mix of yellow and those black-white (ie. grey) pixels drawn earlier underneath.

```
+-----------+-----------+- -
|yellow/grey|yellow/grey|
+-----------+-----------+  ..etc..
|  yellow   |  yellow   |
+-----------+-----------+- -
```

If you draw your rectangles at exact pixel boundaries, that anti-alias bleed won't be visible.

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/3HmVT/)